# select arrow hidden when disabled

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to hide the arrow on a select input, and for the life of me this does not seem to work in chrome even though it appears to be correct:

```
select:disabled {
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    appearance: none !important;
    &::-ms-expand {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/sandra-willford/pen/NMdjKW

Comment: like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLNVPJ) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you adding all the classes to disabled class. The working solution is

```
select {
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    appearance: none !important;
    &::-ms-expand {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

But If you want to add those styles only on disabled select then do this.

```
<select disabled></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, because I am also using bootstraps .form-control class, BS also adds a background base64 image on it's stylesheet, so added the following fixed the problem.

```
select:disabled {
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield !important;
    -moz-appearance: textfield !important;
    appearance: none !important;
    &::-ms-expand {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've should mentioned that in your question